# CreateProcessA works, CreateProcessW fails with access violation

Tags: c, windows, unicode, utf-8

Following works

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    STARTUPINFOA  start_info = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = { 0 };
    LPSTR str = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\PING.EXE";

    CreateProcessA(
        NULL,
        str,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &start_info,
        &process_info
    );

    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen in

```
C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug
λ ConsoleApplication1.exe

C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug
λ echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

But wide version I want to implement for utf8 support doesn't:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    STARTUPINFOW  start_info = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = { 0 };
    LPWSTR str = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\PING.EXE";

    CreateProcessW(
        NULL,
        str,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &start_info,
        &process_info
    );

    return 0;
}
```

That can be seen in

```
C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug
λ ConsoleApplication1.exe

C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug
λ echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-1073741819
```

I have no clue what is the problem, since both compile without problem

Running second one with debugger leads to this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x744106F2 (KernelBase.dll) in
>   ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0x00C47B68. occurred

Comment: As a side note, wide strings in Windows are UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: I have edited the question to show same thing happens when using variable

Comment: @ben-voigt please reopen as this doesn't seem to be duplicate

Comment: You still are passing a pointer to a literal, in read-only memory.  It's 100% a duplicate.

Comment: The STARTUPINFO parameter also isn't initialized properly.  It's first parameter should be initialized to its size: `start_info.cb = sizeof(start_info);`.

Comment: Allright, yes it's duplicate. Here's how should initialization look like

wchar_t cmd[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\PING.EXE";